# what is change in facebook user id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As my application is old and i have saved user id with php-sdk but for some reason i lost my facebook account and also lost my facebook developer account.

So all user of my application have old user id that is format like `1000011102010....` but when i created new facebook account and created new application it start giving me new format of user id `78102000....` now i am totally lost. i am still using php-sdk everything is same but i am getting different user id

```
$fbuid = $user_info['id'];
```

Comment: Facebook application gives you user application id. It differs from real id for some secure reasons. This id can be used in application and identifies user within it. So you can not, for example, get user profile through his/her real id. You can get user profile only if he/she registered to your app, then take their app user id and retrieve information according to app scope, with app access_tokens and secrets.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked here dozens of times. Please use the search functionality of StackOverflow before posting a new question.

With the graph API v2.0, the so-called app-scoped user_ids have been introduced. See the docs here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids